# Che cosa significa "struscere"?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, regional

Nel romanzo *Mille anni che sto qui*, di Mariolina Venezia, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Di fronte alla chiesa madre, Minguccio il Merciale, detto anche il Pugliese, srotolava le tele che portava sul traino e gliele faceva scorrere sotto gli occhi. Loro le accarezzavano furtive, il percalle gentile per le lenzuola, la scozzese che si vendeva a terremoto per le camicie e le tovaglie, la flanella e la falsa flanella per i calzonetti, il mul'ttone piú pesante per le sottane, il velluto liscio da femmina e quello a coste da maschio, il castoro marrò o lilla, scuro e pesante, per la vesta di matrimonio anche d'estate, la nzarchign, bianca e doppia per le tovaglie e le fodere dei materassi, il raso nero per i sinali eleganti, u casimirr, la lana leggera per i fazzoletti da portare in testa, la gabardine per gli abiti da uomo leggeri e la vigogna per il vestito dello sposo, cosí buona che la tenevano stipata che poi **si strusceva** e quando l'andavano a prendere la trovavano tutta purtusata. 
>         Che bisogno c'è di tutta quella roba che fa solo **struscere** soldi, diceva Vincenzo [...].

Qualcuno di voi saprebbe spiegare cosa significa questo verbo, "struscere"? Immagino si tratti di una voce di origine dialettale: non sono riuscita a trovarla su nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato.

Comment: Ciao!
Complimenti per la scelta del libro. Da madrelingua, ti dico che non è facile da capire nemmeno per me. Ci sono molte parole dialettali.
Io la intrerpreto come "piegare", in questo caso piegavano della stoffa.

Comment: Benvenuta su Italian.SE, @MilenaGuerra! Il tuo post, sebbene sia interessante, sembra più un commento che una vera risposta. Per questa ragione sarà convertito in un commento.

Comment: A me sembra più simile a "sdrucire"

Comment: Ho trovato [questo](https://m.facebook.com/marikashowscio/posts/583617285335164): *La cer s strusc e la prcssion nen camin* = La cera si consuma e la processione non cammina. Quindi, "struscere" potrebbe voler dire "consumare".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Secondo questo [vocabolario di dialetto barlettano](http://www.papagnol.com/barlettano_zingarelli.asp#S), "struscere" significa

> consumare completamente.

Ho trovato anche su parecchi siti web, come per esempio  [questo](http://mikam.altervista.org/proverbi-pugliesi.html), con a volte leggere variazioni nell'ortografia,  il proverbio

> La cer s strusc e la procession nan camin

che può essere tradotto letteralmente come "la cera si consuma e la processione non cammina".

Nel contesto del brano, tanto le stoffe come i soldi si consumavano.

Tale significato è anche riportato dal [*Lessico etimologico italiano*](https://stampa.lei-digitale.it/pdf/LEI%20XIX%20(da-%20%E2%80%93%20de%CC%84tentor).pdf). Secondo questo vocabolario, nei dialetti tarantino, salentino e salentino centrale (leccese), "struscere" significa

> consumare, logorare, sciupare qc. con l'uso e il trascorrere del tempo [...].

Comment: Sì, è una forma dialettale che significa "sperperare", "dilapidare", "consumare inutilmente"; vedi, ad esempio, " *le sólde du carecchjare se le strusce u sciambagnare* " (i soldi dell'avaro li dilapida lo spendaccione); " *a lava' la cape o ciucce, se strusce iacque e sapone* " (a lavare la testa all'asino, si spreca acqua e sapone)

Comment: ... se ne possono vedere alcuni usi qui: http://www.pugliadigitallibrary.it/media/00/00/38/951.pdf